# How to filter posts by count (by searching and counting from the database)?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to create a post filter form in which users can sort posts by title, date etc. Sorting by date, title and custom metadata works great, but how to add sorting by count (by searching and counting from the database)?

HTML:

```
<select name="sortby">
    <option value="">Default</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
    <option value="count">Count</option>
    <option value="title">Title</option>
</select>
<select name="sortdirection">
    <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
    <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
</select>

<button>Filter</button>
<input type="hidden" name="posttype" value="mycustomposttype">
```

functions.php:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $_POST['posttype'], 
    'orderby' => $_POST['sortby'], 
    'order' => $_POST['sortdirection'],
);

if( !empty( $_POST['sortby'] ) && $_POST['sortby'] == 'price' ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = '_item_price';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order'] = $_POST['sortdirection'];
}
```

The function I want to adjust and use in the count filter:

```
function my_prefix_gamipress_earners_count_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'gamipress_earners_count' );
    $id = absint( $atts['id'] );
    $user_earnings = GamiPress()->db->user_earnings;
    return absint( $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$user_earnings} AS ue WHERE ue.post_id = {$id}" ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'gamipress_earners_count', 'my_prefix_gamipress_earners_count_shortcode' );
```